# SQL Server Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have a problem with high frequency inserts. I use a stored procedure to insert data into my table, but I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MyTable'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MyTable'. The duplicate key value is (3001749001, 0, 02/09/2016, abc).
>   The statement has been terminated.

This is my code:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetData]
@Key1 nvarchar(50),
@Key2 int,
@Key3 nvarchar(50),
@Key4 nvarchar(50),
@Data1 nvarchar(100)

AS
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM [dbo].[MyTable] 
                 WHERE [Key1] = @Key1 AND [Key2] = @Key2 AND [Key3] = @Key3 AND [Key4] = @Key4)
BEGIN
  UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
       SET [Data1] = @Data1
          ,[UpdateTime] = getdate()  
       WHERE [Key1] = @Key1 AND [Key2] = @Key2 AND [Key3] = @Key3 AND [Key4] = @Key4
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable]
                        ([Key1]
                        ,[Key2]
                        ,[Key3]
                        ,[Key4]
                        ,[Data1]                        
                        ,[UpdateTime])          
               VALUES
                        (@Key1,
                           @Key2,
                           @Key3,
                           @Key4,
                           @Data1,                           
                           getdate())
END
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: If two connections execute the SP at exactly the same time with the same key, both will see the record doesn't exist and both will insert instead of one inserting and the other updating.  You need to ensure that both don't use the same key or they don't run at the same time.  Or you can catch the exception and retry.

Comment: Just use an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column and let the **database** handle the dirty work of creating proper, unique identity values for you - that'll save you tons of grief and effort !

Comment: If you are not going to allow the table to lock while you run through the procedure you will need to use the `IDENTITY(1,1)` column as marc_s mentions, as there is no way you can guarantee you'll never have key collisions.